# Why can't I use WorldToViewportPoint for 2D Mouse Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to track the movement with my mouse pointer for a object for 2D Ping Pong and my object is going crazy on the Y-Axis. I want to use WorldToViewportPoint but this codeword is rather for 3D Games (I think?). Does anyone of you has an idea why i can use WorldToViewportPoint to track my movement?

(sorry for my terrible english. Im from Germany :). and sorry for my coding skills I just at the beginning)

Thanks for Help!!!

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MausMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var PosY = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition).y; // Get the position of the mouse Pointer

        var VectorPos = new Vector2(0, PosY); // transfrom the position in a vector

        rb.MovePosition(VectorPos); // Put in the Rigidbody
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get your coordinate systems mixed up? The mouse position is in screen coordinates while the ping-pong object is in world coordinates. So try `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse is in screen coordinates while the object is in world coordinates, so you should be using [`Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) instead.

Note that the conversion treats the Z value of the input as distance from the camera. `Input.mousePosition` will give you 0 for the Z value, so you might have to tweak the Z in order for the paddle to appear in the correct plane.